# Are there Rust QuickCheck ports which support running with a seed

Tags: rust, random-seed, seeding, quickcheck, property-based-testing

I'd like to do quickcheck/property-based testing and have it run in CI, but I don't want to add a randomized test to CI (since it could potentially fail when someone else is attempting to merge an unrelated change and force them to re-run).

Are there any Rust property-based testing libraries which support this?

Answer (score 1):

I found that `proptest` supports it: https://docs.rs/proptest/latest/proptest/test_runner/struct.TestRng.html#method.deterministic_rng